# Segmentation fault c++ Hexadecimal Calculator

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, hex, calculator

I keep getting a segmentation fault when I attempt to add a hex number to the current hex number. Here is the line where I'm getting my segmentation fault(I think):

```
newHex->insertTail(sum);
```

Here is the whole program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#undef NULL
const int NULL = 0;
const char SENTINEL = '#';
typedef int element;

class listnode {

    public:
        element data;
        listnode * next;
};

class LList {

    private:
        listnode * head;
        listnode * tail;
        listnode * view;

    public:
        LList();
        ~LList();
        void read();
        listnode* next();
        void print();
        void insertTail(element val);
        void clean();
        //void add(LList operand);
        //void multiply(LList operand);
        element deleteHead();
};

class Calculator {

    public:
        Calculator();
        LList* add(LList& left, LList& right);
        //LList* multiply(LList& left, LList& right);
};

Calculator::Calculator() {

};

LList* Calculator::add(LList& left, LList& right) {
    int sum, carry = 0, lval = 0, rval = 0;
    bool calculating = true;
    listnode *leftNode;
    listnode *rightNode;
    LList* newHex;
    while(calculating) {

        leftNode = left.next();
        rightNode = right.next();

        if(leftNode == NULL) {
            lval = 0;
        }
        else
            lval = leftNode->data;

        if(rightNode == NULL) {
            rval = 0;
        }
        else
            rval = rightNode->data;


        if(leftNode == NULL && rightNode == NULL) {
            calculating = false;
            if(carry != 0) {
                newHex->insertTail(carry);
            }
            break;
        }

        sum = lval + rval + carry;
        carry = 0;
        if(sum >= 16) {
            carry = 1;
            sum -= 16;
        }
        cout << "Segmentation Fault Below :)"  << endl;
        newHex->insertTail(sum);

    }

    return newHex;
};

listnode* LList::next() {
    listnode* temp = view;
    if(temp != NULL)
        view = view->next;

    if(view == NULL) {
    }
    return temp;
};


LList::LList(){
    head = NULL;
    view = NULL;
};


void LList::print() {
    listnode * temp;
    int i = 0;
    string printValues;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        int var = temp -> data;
        char character = ' ';
        if(i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
            printValues += ',';
        i++;    
        if(var > 9 && var < 16)
        {
            character = static_cast <char>(var + 65 - 10);

        }else if (var <= 9 && var >= 0)
            character = static_cast <char>(var + 48);
        printValues += character;
        temp = temp -> next;

    }
    string tempValues;
    for(int i = printValues.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        tempValues += printValues[i];
    cout << tempValues;
    cout << endl;
};

 void LList::read() {
    string userval;
    int i;
    bool parsing = true;
    char curval;
    vector <int> values;
    clean();
    while(parsing) {
        cin >> userval;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < userval.length(); i++) {
            curval = userval[i];    //this is your character
            if(curval >= 48 && curval <= 57)
                values.push_back(static_cast <int>(curval - 
            48));

            if(curval >= 65 && curval <= 70)
                values.push_back(static_cast <int>(curval - 
            65 + 10));

            if(curval == ' ')
                break;

            if(curval == SENTINEL) {
                parsing = false;
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    for(int i = values.size() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        insertTail(values[i]);
    }
}; 

void LList::insertTail(element val) {
    listnode * temp;
    temp = new listnode;
    temp -> data = val;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        view = head;
    }
    else
        tail -> next = temp;
    tail = temp;
};

void LList::clean() {
    while(head != NULL)
        deleteHead();
};

void validCommands() {
    cout << "Valid commands are:" << endl;
    cout << "  e enter  enter the current ";
    cout << "hexadecimal ";
    cout << "number from the keyboard" << endl;
    cout << "  a add        add a new hexadecimal ";
    cout << "number to the current hex. number" << endl;
    cout << "  m multiply   ";
    cout << "multiply a new hexadecimal number ";
    cout << "by the current hex. number" << endl;
    cout << "  h help   show this help menu" << endl;
    cout << "  q quit   quit the program" << endl << endl;
};

/*
void LList::multiply(LList operand) {
    int left, right, product, carry;
    listnode* operandNext = operand.next();
    listnode* currentNode = this->head;
    while(operandNext != NULL) {
        left = operandNext->data;
        right = currentNode->data;
        product = left * right;
        carry = 0;
        if(product >= 16) {
            product -= 16;
            carry = 1;
        }
        if(currentNode == NULL) {
            this->insertTail(left);
        }
        currentNode->data = product;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
        operandNext = operandNext->next;
    }
};
*/

element LList::deleteHead() {
    listnode * temp;
    temp = head;
    head = head -> next;
    delete temp;
    return temp -> data;
};

LList::~LList(){
    delete head;
};

int main() {
    LList L, add,multiply;
    Calculator calc;
    L.insertTail(0);
    char option;
    bool run;
    cout << "Hexadecimal Calculator, Ver 1.0.0 \n";
    cout << endl;



    do {
    cout << "Current Hexadecimal number is: ";
    L.print();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Command (h for help): ";
    cin >> option;
    cout << endl << endl;
        switch(option) {
            case 'e' : 
                cout << "Enter a hexadecimal number ";
                cout << "followed by #: ";
                L.read();
                cout << endl << "Entering completed.";
                cout << endl << endl;
            break;
            case 'a' :  
                cout << "Adding a new hexadecimal number ";
                cout << "to the current hex. number" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Enter a hexadecimal ";
                cout << "number, follow by #: ";
                add.read();
                cout << endl << "Addition completed.";
                cout << endl;
                L = *calc.add(L, add);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 'm' : 
                cout << "Multiplying a new hexadecimal ";
                cout << "number ";
                cout << "to the current hex. number" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Enter a hexadecimal ";
                cout << "number, follow by #: ";
                //multiply.read();
                cout << endl << "Multiplication completed.";
                cout << endl;
                //L.multiply(multiply);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 'h' : validCommands();
            break;
            case 'q' : run = false;
            break;
        };
    } while (run);
        exit(0);

}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: `Here is the line where I'm getting my segmentation fault(I think)` Are you going to be a programmer or a fortune teller? No need to guess the line, really. There are tools that will tell the exact line, values of all variables, stack trace etc. Use a debugger!

Comment: `const int NULL = 0;` - This is not a good idea - makes things confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, the problem is `newHex`, in `Calculator::add()`

You define a pointer to a `LList`

```
LList* newHex;
```

and you use it

```
newHex->insertTail(carry);
[...]
newHex->insertTail(sum);
```

without allocate it.